# Reuse constructor. Pass rvalue to const lvalue and do not repeat implementation

Tags: c++, constructor, c++14, rvalue-reference, pass-by-rvalue-reference

I have an idea how to simplify remove code repeats. Please help me to understand if it usable, good, and may be let's upgrade.

```
struct NetAdres
{
    /*#1*/NetAdres(const std::string &str, uint16_t port);  //#1
    /*#2*/NetAdres(std::string &&str, uint16_t port) : NetAdres(std::move(str), port) {};  //#2
    /*#3*/NetAdres(const char *str, uint16_t port) : NetAdres(std::string(str), port) {};  //#3
}
```

This call

```
NetAdres("192.168.2.3", 80);
```

as far as I understand calls `#3`->`#2`->`#1`. And this call

```
NetAdres(std::string("192.168.2.3"), 80);
```

`#2`->`#1`. Does such implementation give no extra copy of `std::string`?

Comment: If your base case only requires reading a string (i.e., `const std::string&`), then there's no reason to provide the other overloads. Temporary strings will bind to it just fine.

Comment: Why would any of those call one of the others?  There's a mismatch in number of parameters.

Comment: Your calls to #1 include AF_INET, but the signature of #1 does not allow it.

Comment: #2 and # 3 seems to call some undefined 3 parameter ''base" class ctor?

Comment: And you try to bind a `const std::string` to a `std::string&&`. Then move from it. lol

Comment: **code fixed.** Please reread. `const char*` overload need explicitly 100%. I have a reason for that. The main point of this question is #2-#1

Comment: #2 calls #2, not #1 – `NetAdres(std::string &&str, uint16_t port) : NetAdres(std::move(str), port) {}` is infinitely recursive. Attempting to run this code at all would have made that obvious.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to pass by value, e.g.:

```
struct NetAddress
{
    std::string addr_;
    uint16_t port_;
    NetAddress(std::string addr, uint16_t port)
        : addr_(std::move(addr)) // <--- always involves one move
        , port_(port)
    {}
};
```

And then call it like:

```
NetAddress a("example.com", 443);

// or
std::string addr("example.com");
NetAddress b(addr, 443);

// or with move
NetAddress c(std::move(addr), 443);
```

The downside is that it always involves one `std::move`, which may or may not be elided.

With `g++-6.2` and pre-C++11 `std::string`, the last line with `std::move` generates the shortest assembly code.